# A word that means "to convert from a unit-less quantity to a unit-ed quantity"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the value 30, which is a unit-less or dimension-less value. To convert this to a "unit-ed" value, I append the "ms" suffix (or more formally, multiply the dimensionless value by 1ms), giving me the value "30ms" or "30 milliseconds".

Is there a name for this process of converting a unit-less value to a unit-ed one? Off the top of my head, I can think of the non-standard "unitize", but I'm wondering if there is a standard word.

Comment: It makes no sense.  If the number is unitless, how do you know what units to give it??

Comment: When I used to teach maths, I'd stress that we'd drop units (once we were sure there were no mixed units) and use a purely numerical model  when performing necessary calculations ('physics' used to use an overly complex strategem). We'd add a caveat (working in m, s) etc. At the end, we'd convert back from pure numbers to the physical measure (eg, 4.23m; $34.56). Units and algebraic unknowns do not mix well in complex calculations.

Comment: You are essentially multiplying the unitless number 30 by the unit 1 m.  If you reverse this you express it as multiplying the unit 1 m by the the unitless number 30.  This  is like starting with 1m and adding 1m to it 29 times.

Comment: To be a hair less sarcastic, you are *annotating* the numbers.

Comment: The number is always unit-ed, now you’re just showing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I've heard it used in quite this way, but I would say *dimension*.

This is an extension of the OED's definition 2 (for the verb):

> *transitive*. To mark the dimensions on (a working drawing, diagram, or
>   sketch). Chiefly in *past participle* and *participial adjective*.

So, "Having completed the calculation with pure numbers, we dimensioned them for the report".

Comment: I won't add another answer, but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimensionalize#English) has << **dimensionalise/ize** (third-person singular simple present dimensionalizes, present participle dimensionalizing, simple past and past participle dimensionalized) Verb (transitive) _To provide with dimensions_ >> I'm not sure I'd use this for writing the final answer in yen.

Comment: The iWeb corpus has 3 instances of _dimension_ as a verb - all are clearly the OED's definition. It has no instances of _dimensionalize_, but GloWbE has 7, from N America and Singapore/Malaysia. I can't clearly work out what any of them mean, but I **think** they are marketing-speak for "embiggen".

Comment: It should be emphasised that dimensioning in this sense is merely a matter of **marking**, that is of writing something down. The word 'converting', used by the OP, is misleading here, as it leaves an impression that this is a mathematical operation of some kind (which is why @Hot Licks initially commented that the question made no sense), while it is, in fact, only a matter of making explicit something that has been understood to be there all along (as pointed out by @Unrelated).

Answer (score 1):

**qualify**

> to characterize by naming an attribute - [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qualify)

In this example, you are naming the "units of measurement" attribute

Comment: Could you add an example from life where the term is actually used in the 'convert from a unit-less quantity to a unit-ed quantity' subsense? I've never seen it used this way.